# 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host' with Mass Transit and RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I have a fresh installation of RabbitMq and everything was working fine sending messages with Mass Transit and RabbitMQ. Suddently, this happened when I try to send a message ...

---

> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.OperationInterruptedException
> HResult=0x80131500   Message=The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP
> close-reason, initiated by Library, code=541, text='Unexpected
> Exception', classId=0, methodId=0, cause=System.IO.IOException: Unable
> to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was
> forcibly closed by the remote host..  --->
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was
> forcibly closed by the remote host.    at
> System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
> Int32 count)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
> System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
> Int32 count)    at System.IO.BufferedStream.ReadByteSlow()    at
> RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.InboundFrame.ReadFrom(Stream reader, Byte[]
> frameHeaderBuffer, ArrayPool`1 pool, UInt32 maxMessageSize)    at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler.ReadFrame()    at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Connection.MainLoopIteration()    at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Connection.MainLoop()   Source=RabbitMQ.Client   StackTrace:    at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SimpleBlockingRpcContinuation.GetReply(TimeSpan timeout)    at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ModelBase.ModelRpc(MethodBase method, ContentHeaderBase header, Byte[] body)    at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Model._Private_ChannelOpen(String outOfBand)    at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Connection.CreateModel() at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.RabbitMqConnectionContext.<CreateModel>b__26_0() at MassTransit.Util.ChannelExecutor.SynchronousFuture`1.Run()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---    at MassTransit.Util.ChannelExecutor.d__14`1.MoveNext()    at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.RabbitMqConnectionContext.<CreateModel>d__26.MoveNext() at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.RabbitMqConnectionContext.<CreateModelContext>d__27.MoveNext() at MassTransit.SupervisorExtensions.CreateAgentPipe`2.d__4.MoveNext()
> at
> MassTransit.Internals.TaskExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2_0`1.<<OrCanceled>g__WaitAsync|0>d.MoveNext() at MassTransit.SupervisorExtensions.<CreateAgent>d__5`2.MoveNext()
> at
> MassTransit.Internals.TaskExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2_0`1.<<OrCanceled>g__WaitAsync|0>d.MoveNext() at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.ModelContextFactory.<CreateSharedModel>d__4.MoveNext() at MassTransit.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.d__7.MoveNext()
> at MassTransit.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.<Send>d__7.MoveNext()    at MassTransit.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.d__7.MoveNext()
> at
> MassTransit.SupervisorExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass5_0`2.<<CreateAgent>g__HandleSupervisorTask|0>d.MoveNext() at MassTransit.SupervisorExtensions.<CreateAgent>d__5`2.MoveNext()
> at
> MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.ScopeModelContextFactory.d__4.MoveNext()
> at MassTransit.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.<Send>d__7.MoveNext()    at MassTransit.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.d__7.MoveNext()
> at MassTransit.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.d__7.MoveNext()
> at
> MassTransit.Transports.HostConfigurationRetryExtensions.d__0.MoveNext()

---

My Mass Transit setup is pretty straight forward...

---

```
  conf.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
        {
            cfg.Host("localhost", "/", h =>
            {
                h.Username("guest");
                h.Password("guest");
            });
        });
```

---

And my RabbitMQ Status is this .....

---

> Status of node rabbit@DEV-BEGUEST ... Runtime
>
> OS PID: 6808 OS: Windows Uptime (seconds): 818 Is under maintenance?:
> false RabbitMQ version: 3.11.16 RabbitMQ release series support
> status: supported Node name: rabbit@DEV-BEGUEST Erlang configuration:
> Erlang/OTP 26 [erts-14.0] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10]
> [async-threads:1] [jit:ns] Crypto library: OpenSSL 3.1.0 14 Mar 2023
> Erlang processes: 405 used, 1048576 limit Scheduler run queue: 1
> Cluster heartbeat timeout (net_ticktime): 60
>
> Plugins
>
> Enabled plugin file:
> c:/Users/Xavi/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/enabled_plugins Enabled
> plugins:
>
> - rabbitmq_management  * amqp_client  * rabbitmq_web_dispatch  *
>   cowboy  * cowlib  * rabbitmq_management_agent
>
> Data directory
>
> Node data directory:
> c:/Users/Xavi/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/db/rabbit@DEV-BEGUEST-mnesia
> Raft data directory:
> c:/Users/Xavi/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/db/rabbit@DEV-BEGUEST-mnesia/quorum/rabbit@DEV-BEGUEST
>
> Config files
>
> - c:/Users/Xavi/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/advanced.config
>
> Log file(s)
>
> - *
>   c:/Users/Xavi/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/log/rabbit@DEV-BEGUEST.log  *
>   c:/Users/Xavi/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/log/rabbit@DEV-BEGUEST_upgrade.log
>
> Alarms
>
> (none)
>
> Memory
>
> Total memory used: 0.0885 gb Calculation strategy: rss Memory high
> watermark setting: 0.4 of available memory, computed to: 5.9848 gb
>
> code: 0.0375 gb (38.74 %) other_proc: 0.0289 gb (29.85 %)
> other_system: 0.0223 gb (23.04 %) other_ets: 0.003 gb (3.07 %) binary:
> 0.0015 gb (1.59 %) atom: 0.0015 gb (1.53 %) metrics: 0.0011 gb (1.1 %) reserved_unallocated: 0.001 gb (1.08 %) plugins: 0.0007 gb (0.74 %)
> mgmt_db: 0.0002 gb (0.16 %) mnesia: 0.0001 gb (0.08 %)
> connection_other: 0.0 gb (0.03 %) msg_index: 0.0 gb (0.03 %)
> quorum_ets: 0.0 gb (0.03 %) quorum_queue_procs: 0.0 gb (0.0 %)
> quorum_queue_dlx_procs: 0.0 gb (0.0 %) stream_queue_procs: 0.0 gb (0.0
> %) stream_queue_replica_reader_procs: 0.0 gb (0.0 %)
> connection_readers: 0.0 gb (0.0 %) connection_writers: 0.0 gb (0.0 %)
> connection_channels: 0.0 gb (0.0 %) queue_procs: 0.0 gb (0.0 %)
> queue_slave_procs: 0.0 gb (0.0 %) stream_queue_coordinator_procs: 0.0
> gb (0.0 %) allocated_unused: 0.0 gb (0.0 %)
>
> File Descriptors
>
> Total: 2, limit: 65439 Sockets: 0, limit: 58893
>
> Free Disk Space
>
> Low free disk space watermark: 0.05 gb Free disk space: 67.6863 gb
>
> Totals
>
> Connection count: 0 Queue count: 0 Virtual host count: 1
>
> Listeners
>
> Interface: [::], port: 15672, protocol: http, purpose: HTTP API
> Interface: [::], port: 25672, protocol: clustering, purpose:
> inter-node and CLI tool communication Interface: [::], port: 5672,
> protocol: amqp, purpose: AMQP 0-9-1 and AMQP 1.0 Interface: 0.0.0.0,
> port: 5672, protocol: amqp, purpose: AMQP 0-9-1 and AMQP 1.0

---

Windows firewall is OFF.

I don't really understand why this was working and suddently I get this error.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using Erlang 26 with RabbitMQ 3.11.x. You have to use Erlang 25 for RAbbitMQ 3.11.x  See https://www.rabbitmq.com/which-erlang.html

Erlang 26 is not officially supported yet, we are working on it; at some point in 3.12.x will be supported.

Comment: You can approve the answer for future readers. Thank you

Comment: Sorry! I've just approve it. Thank you again. But I cannot mark the answer as 'useful' because when pressing the button a message says that I don't have enough reputation yet. ;(

Comment: See also Rabbitmq & Erlang Unsupported Series Compatibility Matrix (https://www.rabbitmq.com/docs/which-erlang#eol-series).